# OBDC driver string translation depends on Control Panel/Regional Settings

Tags: c++, sql-server, windows, winapi, locale

I have a C++ program, which uses "SQL server" driver to connect to an MSSQL database.
It inserts/reads an UTF-8 encoded string to/from a `varchar` field on the server. This operation works completely well
in case of particular regional settings. Otherwise UTF-8 continuation bytes will be stripped by the ODBC driver.
I would like to implement a solution, which does not depend on regional settings of Windows OS.

Inserting works like this:

```
const char chineseStr[] = "\xE5\x8A\xA0\xE6\xB2\xB9\xE7\xAB\x99";
...                 // some logic
...                 // pass chineseStr gdal111.dll (Geospatial Data Abstraction Library)
...                 // it generates "INSERT INTO ..." query string and after that executes it:
SQLExecDirect(...)  // at this point \xE5 is preserved, it was not stripped to \x61
```

After this call the "SQL server" driver sends data to the server. Originally a wrong result appeared in
the database: `\x61\x8A\xA0\x61\x32\x31\xE7\xAB\x99`. But I knew that the exactly same program works well
in an other client environment. After debugging registry accesses of the running process, I've guessed
that something is wrong with loaded codepages, therefore I changed this setting in Control Panel:
*Region and Language / Administrative / Language for non-Unicode programs*. It was "*English (United States)*"
and I've changed it to "*Hungarian (Hungary)*" and restarted the computer as it was requested. Atfer this,
everything worked well, so my program could read and write UTF-8 fields correctly, and the database
representation was also correct.

Other possible solutions did not work. I have tried to add "*[AutoTranslate=no](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx)*" to the connect string,
and debugged like this:

```
SQLAllocConnect(...);      // we are in gdal111.dll
...
SQLDriverConnect(...)      // parameters after return:
   //InConnectionString:  DRIVER=SQL Server;Server=MyServerName;Database=MY_DATABASE;UID=username;PWD=passw;AutoTranslate=no;
   //OutConnectionString: DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=MyServerName;UID=username;PWD=passw;WSID=win_username;DATABASE=MY_DATABASE;AutoTranslate=no
```

Based on `OutConnectionString` I assume that the given connect option reached the driver, but it had no effect.

Locale related standard functions (e.g: `std::setlocale`) did not have any effect. After that I experimented with
[GetLocaleInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call using this code:

```
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IDEFAULTLANGUAGE, (LPTSTR)&buf, bufsize);       std::wcout << buf << ",";
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IDEFAULTCOUNTRY, (LPTSTR)&buf, bufsize);        std::wcout << buf << ",";
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IDEFAULTCODEPAGE, (LPTSTR)&buf, bufsize);       std::wcout << buf << ",";
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE, (LPTSTR)&buf, bufsize);   std::wcout << buf << ",";
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IDEFAULTMACCODEPAGE, (LPTSTR)&buf, bufsize);    std::wcout << buf << std::endl;

GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IDEFAULTLANGUAGE, (LPTSTR)&buf, bufsize);     std::wcout << buf << ",";
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IDEFAULTCOUNTRY, (LPTSTR)&buf, bufsize);      std::wcout << buf << ",";
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IDEFAULTCODEPAGE, (LPTSTR)&buf, bufsize);     std::wcout << buf << ",";
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE, (LPTSTR)&buf, bufsize); std::wcout << buf << ",";
GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, LOCALE_IDEFAULTMACCODEPAGE, (LPTSTR)&buf, bufsize);  std::wcout << buf << std::endl;
```

I've run it after setting different languages for the above mentioned "*Language for non-Unicode programs*":

```
English (United States) // doesn't work
040e,36,852,1250,10029
0409,1,437,1252,10000

Hungarian (Hungary)     // <-- insert/read WORKS (latin2)
040e,36,852,1250,10029
040e,36,852,1250,10029

German (Germany)        // doesn't work
040e,36,852,1250,10029
0407,49,850,1252,10000

Greek (Greece)          // doesn't work
040e,36,852,1250,10029
0408,30,737,1253,10006

Turkish (Turkey)        // doesn't work
040e,36,852,1250,10029
041f,90,857,1254,10081

German (Germany)        // +all regional setting set to German in Control Panel --> doesn't work
0407,49,850,1252,10000
0407,49,850,1252,10000

Croatian (Croatia)      // <-- insert/read WORKS (latin2)
040e,36,852,1250,10029
041a,385,852,1250,10082
```

This output means, that [codepage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 852 or 1250 disables string translation on the client. I don't
understand why others won't work like this, and what kind of code page difference could result a string
translation. "*English (United States)*" is set on the server, but I think it is not relevant.
Perhaps [SetLocaleInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would solve the problem, but it returned `ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS` when I've
tried to set system locales. I didn't find example code for this, anyway it could be not permitted.

How could I implement a solution which does not depend on *Control Panel / Regional Settings*, and
does not need a restart? Or is there an SQL driver option which completely disables client side
string translation?

### Other details:

- **OS**: Windows 7 SP1
- **"SQL Server" driver**: 6.01.7601.17514

Comment: The question became obsolete now, I used an other approach to solve the problem. But now I have found an application [(Microsoft Applocale)](http://microsoft-applocale.software.informer.com/1.3/), which makes Win restart unnecessary. Originally I was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the unicode versions of the various ODBC API functions.

[KB294169: DOC: Explanation of Length Arguments for Unicode ODBC Functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/294169) attempts to document the behaviour of some of how Unicode works in ODBC API

> The ODBC Driver Manager version 3.5 or later supports both ANSI and Unicode versions of all functions that accept pointers to character strings or SQLPOINTER in their arguments. The Unicode functions are implemented as functions with a suffix of "W", such as **SQLExecDirectW** and **SQLGetInfoW**.

For example:

```
| Ansi          | Unicode (Wide) | 
|---------------|----------------|
| SQLExecDirect | SQLExecDirectW |
| SQLGetInfo    | SQLGetInfoW    |
| SQLConnect    | SQLConnectW    |
```

You pass the functions UTF-16 versions of each string, and you pass the length of the strings in *characters* (not bytes).

You can find the functions in `sqlucode.h`

> This is the the unicode include for ODBC Core functions

And if you define `UNICODE` it should automatically redefine SQLExecDirect to use SQLExecDirectW:

```
//---------------------------------------------
// Mapping macros for Unicode
//---------------------------------------------
#ifndef SQL_NOUNICODEMAP    // define this to disable the mapping
#ifdef  UNICODE

#define SQLExecDirect       SQLExecDirectW
```

Comment: My program uses ODBC API through gdal111.dll, so this wouldn't be a trivial change. It is an open source library, thus the change is possible, but I'd like a solution without it. I've experienced that a client environment change solves the problem, without any modification to the executable. My question is that how could I make an executable which ignores these environment settings, and uses its own ones.

Comment: @szkj I would hope, i don't know, that the library allows opting into use of Unicode versions. But in the end, if the ODBC system says that it's a string of 8-bit characters, then that's what it is.